# 2 in one convertible laptop to easel mode optimization

Tags: hardware, hybrid

I have a 2 in one convertible HP pavilion laptop. On Windows I can flip it the whole way around and turn it into a laptop, or put it in easel mode so that the keyboard is disabled and when I set it on my lap keyboard down no key presses would be detected. This is not working on my Ubuntu 16.04.

Also, on Windows, when I put the 2 in one into tent mode, the screen automatically flips for me. (don't use tent THAT much but do occasionally). I know I can flip the screen on settings but that's a bit cumbersome.

The second feature (screen flip) I can do without, but the first one (keyboard disabled when flipped) I really need. Any way to get this running? thanks!

Comment: answer solved by instructions in article http://askubuntu.com/questions/160945/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-laptops-internal-keyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None that I'm aware of or could find. See https://askubuntu.com/a/572270/570692

As it says in the question, there are some Dell convertibles running 12.04, but I know Dell uses it's own proprietary drivers and background services to get their devices running.

You could write custom scripts to i.e. disable the keyboard and turn on onboard (the on-screen-keyboard). I don't know about the sensors that make windows switch automatically. Maybe you can access those via /sys/class/... if they are recognized by the kernel out of the box, but I wouldn't bet on it. You can bind your scripts to keyboard shortcuts or make a launcher.
You can make your life a lot easier, but it's a bit of work to get started.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not experienced. Unfortunately this is bad news because it will make tablet mode difficult to use. Also that link doesn't give much about keyboard shutdown. What type of script would be required to turn off/on the keyboard? sorry for my inexperience

Comment: See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91078). You will have to see if the id stays the same when connecting USB input devices etc. It's gonna take a lot of tweaking and fiddling I'm afraid. Good reference to learn scripting is [tldp](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html).

Comment: tried that and got results in http://hastebin.com/igebujotux.coffee

Comment: wonder why it ends in .coffee lol

Comment: Works for me... Did you try a "real" id and not the virtual core pointer (= 2) ? (you would disable every mouse, touchpad, etc connected now and in the future until you enable it again)

Comment: Try disabling your power button (= 6) (only short single presses, don't press and hold obviously). Should not need sudo. Also if you want to disable your physical keyboard (seems to be id 13 for you) you should not disable id 3, as that would also disable onscreen keyboards and any other stuff you connect as well.

Comment: Well, it seems you can't disable ids 2 and 3. For good reason. As I said, that would not be useful.

Comment: ok I figured it out now. Thanks @jr98 for your help. http://askubuntu.com/questions/160945/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-laptops-internal-keyboard was the article that helped